# Visual Basic Label include text and expression

Tags: vb.net, label, expression

This is quite embarrassing actually that I don't know how to do this, I've tried 3 different versions of syntax and searched overflow for about 4 pages, I want the label to hold a percentage sign and an expression, how do I do this? Here's my logic.

```
AIbasehealth.Text = "%" And Integer / 5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [`ToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3hfd35ad%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) Method of your Expression. Also the direction of your division operator makes a difference [`/` and `\` are different where `\` is for integer division](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6ex274z%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

i.e.

```
AIbasehealth.Text = "%" + (theInteger / 5).ToString
```

or

```
AIbasehealth.Text = "%" + (theInteger \ 5).ToString
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. :) I remember that you've helped me before.

Answer (score 1):

Use `&` string concat operator or `String.Format()` method.

```
AIbasehealth.Text = "%" & (varInteger / 5)
```

OR

```
AIbasehealth.Text = String.Format("% {0}",varInteger / 5))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int theInteger = 50;
AIbasehealth.Text = "%" + (theInteger / 5);
```

Comment: Doesn't work it says that % cant be changed to a double. :\ (even though its set to integer, *facepalm*) "Conversion from string "%" to type 'Double' is not valid."